# Simplest way to tweet when new files are added to a github repo

Tags: git, twitter, github

Is there any way to get a machine-readable alert when a new file is added to a github repo? I found a way to see an atom feed of commits, but the feed doesn't include any breakdown of activity (files added, changed, etc).

The eventual goal would be to send a tweet when a file is added for the first time. Ideally the method would be something simple I could use with, say, http://ifttt.com.

The repo in question is not my own, btw.

Comment: It seems like if you don't want to poll for repository updates, your best bet is to use [post-recieve hooks on GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/post-receive-hooks). Would you be able to ask the owner of this repository (or anyone with access to its settings) if they could set up web hooks for you?

Comment: @NicolasMcCurdy That might be possible – if you put that in an answer, we can see what kind of votes it gets!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you can get permission from one of the repository owners/admins:**
Use [post-receive hooks on GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/post-receive-hooks). I'm not sure if you can limit them to files being created, but you can at least get tweets for new commits set up very easily.

**If you don't have permission:**
Use a library like [Octokit](http://octokit.github.io/) (currently supports Ruby, Objective-C, and .NET) or the [GitHub API](http://developer.github.com/) and manually poll for updates to the repository, saving the tree of files on each check. Whenever a tweet-worthy event (like a new file) is found, use a Twitter library (like [the twitter gem for Ruby](https://github.com/sferik/twitter)) or the [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api) to make a tweet.

Comment: FWIW you can also get an atom feed of all commits at http://github.com/username/reponame/commits/master.atom which you can easily use through ifttt -- but there's no way to filter it for new files only.

Comment: I was able to get the repo creator to add a WebHook link -- I wrote a cgi file in python and put it on a public server I have access to. I used the json and twitter modules to capture the incoming json, process it, and create a tweet.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your repository site and goto settings, under service hooks you can select twitter then you have to supply oauth information which you have retrieved from twitter and hit update settings

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this will work if I don't own the repository.

Comment: how about you fork it and syncronize it regularly?

Comment: @meetar You're right, you'd need to be an admin of the repository.

Comment: @germinator Seems like that should be an answer instead of a comment!

Comment: Forking and synchronizing the repository sounds like a good idea, but it would be hard to automate this if the fork needs to add new commits (due to merge conflicts).

Comment: well if you need to add changes on your own, then do that on another branch and rebase it when syncronizing the fork

Answer (score 0):

There's also a way to do it using a web service called Zapier (http://zapier.com) but the free version only allows 100 hits per month. It also doesn't allow any processing of the json – it flattens it and allows limited object access, but that's it.

But if that's what you're into, here's how you'd do it:

Create a "Web Hook" trigger, and then add the Webhook URL as, natch, a "WebHook URL" at path-to-your-repo/settings/hooks – add the Twitter service as the action, and link to the account of your choice. Then you can create a tweet using some of the information from the json – but not all.